# Accesing two different rows simultaneously in C

Tags: c, rows, simultaneous

Suppose I have a data set arranged in the following way

```
19 10 1 1
12 15 1 1
13 12 4 5
10 5  2 3
...
```

and so on, at a particular iteration in a for loop I have to read only the 1st and the 4th row and in the next iteration I have to access some other set of rows,for example

```
1st iteration:

1st row: 19 10 1 1
4th row: 10 5  2 3
```

i will access my data using the fscanf() function. But how will i ensure that I choose only the 1st and 4th rows or any two rows for that matter at a given iteration?

(I have not considered reading it into a 2D array since the size of data set is 10^8 )

Thank you.

Comment: read your input into a 2d array, then access wherever you want. What are you stuck on?

Comment: I do not want to do that since my data set size is 10^8 so it becomes very slow.

Comment: if you want to be able to access "any two rows at a given iteration", then you have to store it somewhere. 10^8 isn't as big as you might think it is. Reading from a file instead of memory is guaranteed to be much slower.

Comment: If each line is the same number of characters (call it `N`), then you can just `fseek(fp, N*row, SEEK_SET)` to get to a row, then `fscanf` the row.  If each line is NOT the same number of characters, I suggest making each line the same otherwise there is no good way to random access your file other than some complicated scanning and remembering of line offsets.

Comment: That's the same answer I posted.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Not exactly.  Your solution was more general where you did not assume anything about the lines.  I gave a solution to the easy case where each line was exactly the same length, where you don't have to scan and remember line offsets.

Comment: Note that `fscanf()` and friends don't care about newlines.  If you want to process lines, you will need to use a different input primitive.  Are all your rows the same size?  Same number of entries? Same number of bytes?  One hundred million entries of size 4 bytes each is less than 0.5 GiB memory; are you sure you can afford the access time reading the file but not the space in storing the file in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you read through your data (say, stored in a standard file), get byte offsets for rows by looking for row delimiters (a newline character). You can then read out rows based on the start and end byte offset with C pointer arithmetic on a `FILE *` and `fseek()`. Storing a few byte offsets (an eight byte `long` or equivalent, often) is cheap.

Comment: Sorry Alex,I couldn't understand the technique. Could you elaborate ? (I'm still a rookie with minimal knowledge)

Comment: If your data table is stored in a file, look through your file for newline characters (assuming that is a row delimiter on your platform) and store offsets in an array. When you want row `N`, you retrieve the start offset `N` and end offset `N+1` and read out the bytes between these offsets with `fseek()`.